# Where is system default environment variable set in MAC OS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, bash

I am using macOS High Sierra V10.13.6. I can set up my custom environment variables in .bash_profile. But where is the system default environment variables are stored in the mac system

For Ex:

If i type `echo $HOME` in terminal i get the output as `/Users/parithibang`

Where is this $HOME variable is been set up in the Mac Machine?

In which path this is been set?

Comment: Generally speaking, some env variables are set at login (and inherited), some are set by the shell automatically when it starts, some are set by the user. HOME for instance can be set by the shell automatically by asking the system about the location of your home folder.